# UserDefaults Bool Key Getting Deleted

Tags: ios, bundle, nsuserdefaults

I am creating a userDefault bool key that remains valid until I try to change the value of the key. After I change the value of the key, the key seems to disappear from the application bundle. For example, the following code is in my init routine of my GameManager (which is a singleton serving all levels of my game app) and runs when my app is first loaded:

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];   // get the shared defaults object
    if (defaults) {

        if ([defaults boolForKey:@"Sound Effects ON"]) {
            isSoundEffectsON = [defaults boolForKey:@"Sound Effects ON"];
        }
        else {
            [defaults setBool: YES forKey:@"Sound Effects ON"];
            isSoundEffectsON = YES;

            [defaults synchronize]; // save the initial state
        }
    }
```

When this code is entered for the first time, the execution path take the else clause because the userDefault for @"Sound Effects ON" does not currently exist. If I do nothing else to @"Sound Effects ON" and restart the app (thus reentering this code), the execution path takes the if clause and retrieves the stored value of @"Sound Effects ON" (which indicates that the key has been successfully stored in the application bundle).

Later when one of my game levels is running and the user decides to change the value of this key, the following code executes:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];   // get the shared defaults object
if ([[GameManager sharedGameManager] isSoundEffectsON]) {
    [[GameManager sharedGameManager] setIsSoundEffectsON:NO];

    if (defaults) {
        // Update the state for sound effects
        [defaults setBool: NO forKey:@"Sound Effects ON"];

        [defaults synchronize]; // save the current state
    }
} else {
    [[GameManager sharedGameManager] setIsSoundEffectsON:YES];

    if (defaults) {
        // Update the state for sound effects
        [defaults setBool: YES forKey:@"Sound Effects ON"];

        [defaults synchronize]; // save the current state
    }
}
```

If isSoundEffects was previously on, then @"Sound Effects ON" bool is set to NO and the userDefault is synchronized (presumably to save the value). When this execution path is taken, it appears to remove the userDefault for this key from the application bundle. I say that because when the app is reloaded and the code in the GameManager init executes again, the else clause runs indicating that there is no userDefault key for @"Sound Effects ON".

What am I missing? Why is this key disappearing?

Comment: this doesn't answer your question, but you can look at the raw contents of your NSUserDefaults by going to the "`~/Library/Preferences/`" directory in Terminal.app, then typing in "`defaults read ___________.plist`" (where the blank line is the bundle ID for your app).  If your ID is "`com.jeffb6688.gameapp`", then you would do "`defaults read com.jeffb6688.gameapp.plist`".  You can then see if your "`Sound Effects ON`" bool is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is not disappearing. `boolForKey:` returns the BOOL value itself, so if you set it to NO, then the code `if ([defaults boolForKey:@"Sound Effects ON"]) {...}` will, correctly, not execute its block. If you want to test for the *presence* of the key rather than its value, you should use `objectForKey:` which will return either `nil`, indicating the key does not exist, or an `NSNumber` (from which you can get the BOOL value by asking for its `boolValue`). For example:

```
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"Sound Effects ON"]) {
    // key is set
    BOOL value = [defaults boolForKey:@"Sound Effects ON"];
} else {
    // key is not set
}
```

That all being said, if all you're trying to do is to specify that YES is the default value, you can get rid of that logic altogether and use `registerDefaults:` to specify the values that NSUserDefaults should have before a value is set via `setX:forKey:`. For example:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] registerDefaults:@{"Sound Effects ON": @YES}];
```

Call this in your app delegate before you try to access the defaults. You should only call this once with all the keys for which you want specific default values.

Answer (score 1):

The BOOL being set to `NO` is effectively the same as the key not existing. In both cases `if ([defaults boolForKey:@"Sound Effects ON"]) {` will not trigger.

Your issue appears to be a basic misunderstanding of how booleans work, or how `if` statements work.

For instance, this code:

```
    if ([defaults boolForKey:@"Sound Effects ON"]) {
        isSoundEffectsON = [defaults boolForKey:@"Sound Effects ON"];
    }
```

Is equal to

```
    if ([defaults boolForKey:@"Sound Effects ON"]) {
        isSoundEffectsON = YES;
    }
```

There is no need to request the value from user defaults again.